# Patching removable singularities of a function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, inequalities, singularity

How can I make `FunctionDomain` include removable singularities? For instance,

```
FunctionDomain[Sinc[x], x] == True
```

But

```
FunctionDomain[Sin[x]/x, x] == x < 0 || x > 0
```

I would like the latter to return `True` as well.

**EDIT:** I solved the problem by creating a `patch` function that patches removable singularities, as described in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose looking for the points of discontinuity ahead of time, as follows:

```
f[x_] = Sin[x]/x;
Excl =
 Simplify[
  Map[{Limit[f[t], t -> #], x==#} &, 
   x /. Solve[Simplify[Not[FunctionDomain[f[x], x]]], x]
   ]
  ]

(* Out = {{1, x==0}} *)
```

This output is "reversed" in the sense that it is the y value, then the x value, but that is the necessary format for `Piecewise` to be used:

```
g[x_] = Piecewise[Excl, f[x]];
```

This gives you what you want:

```
FunctionDomain[g[x], x]
```

Here's another more complicated example:

```
f2[x_] = Sin[x]/x + (1 - x^2)/(1 - x);
Excl2 =
  Simplify[
   Map[{Limit[f2[t], t -> #], x==#} &, 
    x /. Solve[Simplify[Not[FunctionDomain[f2[x], x]]], x]
    ]
   ];
g2[x_] = Piecewise[Excl2, f2[x]];
Simplify[FunctionDomain[g2[x], x]]
(* Out = True *)
```

I have no idea if this is the nicest or most compact way of doing this, but it works (I think). Here is a black box that does it:

```
smooth[f_] =
 Function[x,
  Piecewise[
   Simplify[
    Map[{Limit[f[t], t -> #], x == #} &, 
     x /. Solve[Simplify[Not[FunctionDomain[f[x], x]]], x]
     ]
    ],
   f[x]]
  ]
```

I originally had this split into two functions, but I've made an edit here, because any use of `x` internal to finding the excluded points won't jive with the pure function we're defining.

```
smooth[f][x]
FunctionDomain[%, x]
(* Out = piecewise definition of smooth[f][x] *)
(* Out = True *)
smooth[f2][x]
FunctionDomain[%, x]
(* Out = piecewise definition of smooth[f][x] *)
(* Out = True *)
```

Both of those give the functions as before, and again confirm that this function has the full domain you want. If you want to do anything serious besides checking the domain, you want to assign this to its own symbol, i.e.

```
h=smooth[f];
h[0]
(* Out = 1 *)
```

If you just try `smooth[f][0]`, the function tries to do what `smooth` normally does while also using a fixed value of `x=0`. That's not going to work.

This all assumes the points of discontinuity of the function are easy enough to find -- particularly, that `Solve` can find them. Of course, there may be cases where that isn't the case, but I wonder if that isn't something where this entire idea would be impractical.

As to your original idea, why doesn't it work (even though the function appears to have the right domain)?

When you do the following:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]/x
smoothe[g_] := Limit[g[y], y -> #] &
FunctionDomain[smoothe[f][x], x]
```

What the call `smoothe[f]` returns is the expression Sin[x]/x.

Then it finds the domain of that function, as written, which is no different than finding the domain of `f[x]` in the first place.

Your `smoothe[f][__]` will give the correct value for numerical values in the blank, but not for symbolic values -- Mathematica will evaluate the limit you've packed up into `smoothe` as if a symbolic `x` would not be the point of discontinuity.

And then, when you ask for the domain, Mathematica balks and says "Sorry, I thought this should be `Sin[x]/x` when I did `smoothe` and now the domain excludes `x==0`, even though `smoothe[f][0]` exists."

(Edit: I goofed on some syntax and some weird self-correcting errors made it hard to detect, but it's fixed.)

Comment: n.b. This is philosophically the same as Bob Hanlon's answer, but with the flexibility to deal with different `f`.

Comment: `FullSimplify[0||x!=0]` evaluates to `x != 0`

Comment: Sorry, this is due to a syntax error I seem to have overlooked. Not sure where my head was, but it's fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on your code, I created a function called `patch` that patches the removable singularities in a function, and can be called directly. I have added it to the question.

Comment: I'm glad my approach was helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can get you started. (Maybe I've forgotten something.)

```
ClearAll[close];  (* close each open inequality if limit exists by adding endpoint *)
close[f_, x_][x_ != a_] := 
  If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a]], x == a, False];
close[f_, x_][x_ < a_] := 
  If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a, Direction -> 1]], x == a, False];
close[f_, x_][x_ > a_] := 
  If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a, Direction -> -1]], x == a, False];
close[f_, x_][a_ < x_] := 
  If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a, Direction -> -1]], x == a, False];
close[f_, x_][a_ > x_] := 
  If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a, Direction -> 1]], x == a, False];
close[f_, x_][a_ < x_ < b_] := {
   If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a, Direction -> -1]], x == a, False], 
   If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> b, Direction -> 1]], x == b, False]};
close[f_, x_][a_ > x_ > b_] := {
   If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> a, Direction -> 1]], x == a, False], 
   If[NumericQ[Limit[f, x -> b, Direction -> -1]], x == b, False]};
close[f_, x_][_] := False;

$ineqheads = (Less | LessEqual | Greater | GreaterEqual | Inequality | Unequal);

SetAttributes[closure, HoldAll];
closure[FunctionDomain[f_, x_]] := closure[Evaluate@FunctionDomain[f, x], f, x];
closure[domain_, f_, x_] := 
 domain || Or @@ Flatten@
     Cases[domain, i : $ineqheads[__] :> close[f, x][i], Infinity] // 
  Simplify;
```

Example:

```
closure[FunctionDomain[Sin[x]/x, x]]
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: This `closure` function seems to give us a way to determine the effective domain of the OP's `smoothe[f[x]]` but doesn't give us a new function. Is that what you are proposing?

Comment: I don't think `closure[FunctionDomain[Exp[-1/x], x]]` should be `True`

Comment: @CarlWoll No, it shouldn't. I knew that. My example is `x/Abs[x]`. You have to match left & right side limits, which I omitted. Any solution that relies on `Limit[f, x -> c]` without checking both sides will also have the same problem (i.e. all the other answers so far, too). This is one of those questions where, so far, the effort/reward ratio calls fastidiousness into question, imo.

Comment: I think `Series` might be a better tool

Comment: @CarlWoll You must have an idea that eludes me.  `Series` on `Exp[-1/x]` and `Exp[-1/x^2]` return similar looking results.

Comment: Ignoring essential singularities, if you can expand around a point without a pole, then the singularity is removable. For essential singularities, possibly you can just look at the leading term

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by creating a `patch` function that patches removable singularities:

```
(* Returns the two-sided limit, if it exists *)

twoSidedLimit[f_, x_] := Block[{
   r = Limit[f@t, t -> x, Direction -> 1],
   l = Limit[f@t, t -> x, Direction -> -1]
   }, ConditionalExpression[r, r == l]]

(* Patches removable singularities in a function *)

patch[f_][x_] := 
 Piecewise[
  ReleaseHold@
   Cases[Reduce@! FunctionDomain[f@t, t], 
    t == c_ -> {twoSidedLimit[Hold@f, c], x == c}, {0, Infinity}], 
  f@x]
```

For example,

```
TableForm@Prepend[{
     #[x],
     FullSimplify@FunctionDomain[#[x], x],
     FullSimplify@FunctionDomain[patch[#][x], x],
     patch[#][0]
     } & /@ {
    # &
    , Piecewise[{{99, # != 0}}, Undefined] &
    , Piecewise[{{99, # == 0}}, Undefined] &
    , #*Cos[1/#] &
    , (# + #^2)/# &
    , Sin[#]/# &
    , Log[1 + #]/# &
    , Sin[#]/# + Tan[#] &
    (*,Exp[1/#]&*)
    }, {"f[x]", "dom[f]", "dom[patch[f]]", 
   "patch[f][0]"}]
```

outputs

```
{
 {"f[x]", "dom[f]", "dom[patch[f]]", "patch[f][0]"},
 {x, True, True, 0},
 {ConditionalExpression[99, x != 0], x != 0, True, 99},
 {ConditionalExpression[99, x == 0], x == 0, x == 0, 99},
 {x Cos[1/x], x != 0, True, 0},
 {(x + x^2)/x, x != 0, True, 1},
 {Sin[x]/x, x != 0, True, 1},
 {Log[1 + x]/x, -1 < x < 0 || x > 0, x > -1, 1},
 {Sin[x]/x + Tan[x], 1/2 + x/\[Pi] \[NotElement] Integers && x != 0, 
  x == 0 || 1/2 + x/\[Pi] \[NotElement] Integers, 1}
}
```

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `FunctionDomain` to include `0` define the function accordingly

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]/x
f[0 | 0.] = Limit[Sin[x]/x, x -> 0];

FunctionDomain[f, x]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what `f` will be ahead of time.